# Convert CVS Repository to SVN in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: svn, netbeans, cvs, netbeans-6.9

I have a large CVS Repository in a Netbeans Java Project. I used to work with CVS for several years, but for some reason the company started to create all of their projects to SVN; next thing I know is that I have to convert my current Netbeans Java CVS Project into a SVN one.

I have been looking over the internets but I haven't found anything useful yet. Does anyone know a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans does not have button "Make me happy". Sorry.

You must checkout sources from SVN and point Netbeans to new file hierarchy...

Note that Netbeans support CVS, SVN and Mercurial VCS out of the box.

If project structure does not changed you can delete CVS dirs and checkout sources from SVN with **--force** (to avoid reconfiguring projects in Netbeans):

```
  $ find . -type d -name CVS -exec rm -r '{}' ';'
  $ svn co --force http://$U:$P@$H
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/) tool to import the CVS history into a Subversion repo.